# bash: find -exec and filenames

Tags: bash, find, exec, w3m

I want to strip the HTML out of few hundred files.

Here's the command I've started with:

```
find -name *.html -exec w3m {} > w3m {}.html.out \;
```

The problem I've run into is that it created one single large .htm.out file (named {}.html.out) -- I want the file I'm using to be named whatever it's original is .out.

For instance, I have

```
2002/filename.html
```

I want to run it through w3m, and get 2002/filename.html.out

Any suggestions? I'm open to other solutions that don't use bash

I'm using cygwin.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The redirection happens outside of `find`. Invoke a subshell.

```
find -name *.html -exec bash -c 'w3m "$1" > w3m-"$1".html.out' w3mout {} \;
```

Comment: Got it to work with this command: 

find -name *.html -exec bash -c 'w3m "$1" > "$1".html.out' w3mout {} \;