# One-Liner command to empty multiple text files in terminal

Tags: bash, shell

How would you go about using a single command to empty multiple text files in terminal?

My thought was that you could use something along these lines...:

```sh
find /var/log/apache2/*log -exec `echo > '{}'` \;
```

I know it's simple enough to create a shell script that would easily do that:

```sh
echo "#!/bin/sh\n\necho \"\" > \"$1\"" > /usr/local/bin/empty && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/empty
```

...

```sh
find /var/log/apache2/*.log -exec empty {} \;
```

But is it possible to do this without creating your own script in a similar manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or use `sed`:

```
sed Q -i *
```

replacing file contents in place by emptiness.

**update with explanation**

`sed` can do all kinds of replacements, e.g. using regular expressions:

```
$ cat /etc/passwd | sed -e s/^[^:]*/USER/
```

with the pattern saying "substitute anything until : with USER", giving:

```
USER:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
USER:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/sh
USER:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/bin/sh
etc etc
```

Adding `-i` in the mix, `sed` can edit files in-place, so you probably NEVER want to do this:

```
$ sed -e s/^[^:]*/USER/ -i /etc/passwd
```

(Note that on e.g. Mac OS X, you need to put in an extra argument after `-i` to provide the "backup suffix", which is used to make backups before `sed` does its magic on your files)

Now the quest is for the shortest `sed` script to lose all input, which is either `d` or `Q`. `d` would delete all input (and then output nothing), `Q` would quit immediately (and output nothing). `Q` is presumably fastest.

Then, the `sarnold` example would look like:

```
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold  10161 2011-12-30 17:47 alternatives.log
-rw-r----- 1 sarnold sarnold  50976 2011-12-30 17:47 auth.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold    759 2011-12-30 17:47 boot.log
$ sed Q -i *.log
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold 0 2011-12-30 17:47 alternatives.log
-rw-r----- 1 sarnold sarnold 0 2011-12-30 17:47 auth.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold 0 2011-12-30 17:47 boot.log
$
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. However, it is very vague. +1 if you can provide a working example and explanation. :)

Comment: This is superbly clever; the `d` is the entire `sed(1)` script, which says "delete". The `-i` asks `sed(1)` to perform the editing "in place", without making back up files. `sed d -i *.log` is the better fit for your question.

Comment: Totally agree. mvds, if you can edit your answer to reflect the description and example @sarnold provided, I'll choose your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Done, but I must say I would not use this in practice. It's funny (like the `tee` method) but one year from now you, or anyone else will completely miss what's going on.

Answer (score 10):

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in /var/log/apache2/*.log; do
  : > "$file"
done
```

Or the one-liner version

```
for file in /var/log/apache2/*.log; do : > "$file"; done
```

If you need to recurse into subdirs, then you can use the following two options:

#### Bash 4.X

```
shopt -s globstar; for file in /var/log/apache2/**.log; do : > "$file"; done
```

#### Posix

```
find /var/log/apache2 -type f -name "*.log" -exec sh -c 'for f; do : > "$f"; done' _ {} +
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the answer, but I'm looking for a oneliner command. (see title) Thanks! :)

Comment: @HighwayofLife I put a 1-liner version of it. I also added another way to do it with `find`

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `: >(tee *.log)` to spawn the `tee(1)` program to perform the truncation:

```
$ ls -l
total 1284
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold  10161 2011-12-30 17:47 alternatives.log
-rw-r----- 1 sarnold sarnold  50976 2011-12-30 17:47 auth.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold    759 2011-12-30 17:47 boot.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold  41377 2011-12-30 17:47 bootstrap.log
-rw-r----- 1 sarnold sarnold      0 2011-12-30 17:47 daemon.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold  73075 2011-12-30 17:47 dpkg.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold   2914 2011-12-30 17:47 fontconfig.log
-rw-r----- 1 sarnold sarnold 152295 2011-12-30 17:47 kern.log
-rw-r----- 1 sarnold sarnold      0 2011-12-30 17:47 lpr.log
-rw-r----- 1 sarnold sarnold    950 2011-12-30 17:47 mail.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold 212115 2011-12-30 17:47 pm-powersave.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold 413195 2011-12-30 17:47 pm-suspend.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold      0 2011-12-30 17:47 pycentral.log
-rw-r----- 1 sarnold sarnold      0 2011-12-30 17:47 ufw.log
-rw-r----- 1 sarnold sarnold      0 2011-12-30 17:47 user.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold 210426 2011-12-30 17:47 Xorg.0.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold  93985 2011-12-30 17:47 Xorg.1.log
$ : >(tee *.log)
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold 0 2011-12-30 17:47 alternatives.log
-rw-r----- 1 sarnold sarnold 0 2011-12-30 17:47 auth.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold 0 2011-12-30 17:47 boot.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold 0 2011-12-30 17:47 bootstrap.log
-rw-r----- 1 sarnold sarnold 0 2011-12-30 17:47 daemon.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold 0 2011-12-30 17:47 dpkg.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold 0 2011-12-30 17:47 fontconfig.log
-rw-r----- 1 sarnold sarnold 0 2011-12-30 17:47 kern.log
-rw-r----- 1 sarnold sarnold 0 2011-12-30 17:47 lpr.log
-rw-r----- 1 sarnold sarnold 0 2011-12-30 17:47 mail.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold 0 2011-12-30 17:47 pm-powersave.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold 0 2011-12-30 17:47 pm-suspend.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold 0 2011-12-30 17:47 pycentral.log
-rw-r----- 1 sarnold sarnold 0 2011-12-30 17:47 ufw.log
-rw-r----- 1 sarnold sarnold 0 2011-12-30 17:47 user.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold 0 2011-12-30 17:47 Xorg.0.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold 0 2011-12-30 17:47 Xorg.1.log
$
```

Comment: I like this method over the first one with a for-loop.  I'll give +1 if you make it more specific to the question by creating .log files and using `: >(tee *.log)` so he doesn't have to name each file.  Although you'll still need to use find or globstar if you want to recurse more than the current dir

Comment: @SiegeX: Excellent suggestion, it drastically improves my example. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Invoke the shell executable in `-exec`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5810316/20862)

Comment: For the benefit of people in the future, mind posting an example?

Comment: @Highway: There's one on the other end of the link.

Comment: C'mon Ignacio, you know we dislike answers that are just links to other answers...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It's not exactly an example which answers this question.